# Unable to Instantiate seleniumwire + undetected_chromedriver behind Flask + uWSGI + Nginx app

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, nginx, flask

I am writing a Flask app that takes user information from a web form, opens Google Chrome, and automates browser tasks such as filling forms and clicking webpage buttons using the user's information. After the user submits the form, I instantiate the the browser and create a `webdriver` object which I can use to automate browser tasks.

The key code is as follows:

```
#This function instantiates Selenium's webdriver, enables CAPTCHA-solving via extension.
def instantiate_driver():
    print('We are setting options....')

    #Set the options here.
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('----window-size=1280, 672')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    user_agent = generate_random_user_agent()
    options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}') 
    twocaptcha_path = os.path.abspath('./2captcha')
    options.add_argument(f'--load-extension={twocaptcha_path}')

    #Set paths.
    if sys.platform == 'linux' or sys.platform == 'linux2':
        browser_path = os.path.abspath('/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable')
    elif sys.platform == 'win32':
        browser_path = None
    
    #Set the proxy.
    proxy = 'http://user:password@proxyserverurl:port'
    seleniumwire_options = {'proxy': {'http': proxy, 'https': proxy}}

    #Create the browser. 
    print('We are creating a browser instance...')
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options,
                       browser_executable_path=browser_path,
                       seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)

    #Prepare the browser.
    print('We are going to set the CAPTCHA solver\'s API key...')
    driver = close_extra_tabs(driver)
    driver = set_2captcha_api_key(driver)

    driver.get('about:blank')
    print(f'Driver SID: {driver.session_id}')
    return driver
```

```
@app.route('/automate')
def automate_browser():
    web_form = MyForm()
    if web_form.validate_on_submit():
        driver = instantiate_driver()
    return render_template('my_template.html', web_form=web_form)
```

What I notice is that instantiate_browser() works well when called on its own. It produces a `webdriver` object, connects to the proxy, and accesses the right URLs. However, when I deploy my app using uWSGI and Nginx, I get an error 504. When I check my log file, I get a `chrome not reachable` error.

Here is my uWSGI service configuration and my Nginx configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
http = :5000
module = app:app
master = true
processes = 5
http-websockets = true
gevent = 1000
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/MYURL.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/MYURL.key;
    server_name MYURL www.MYURL;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/PATHTOSOCK/MYPROJECT.sock;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/PATHTOAPP/static;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
}
```

My error message:

```
2024-01-06 02:53:18,676 -  DEBUG -  http://localhost:57780 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 500 0
2024-01-06 02:53:18,676 -  DEBUG -  Remote response: status=500 | data={"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:46716\nfrom chrome not reachable","stacktrace":"#0 0x561b2b01df83 \u003Cunknown>\n#1 0x561b2acd6b2b \u003Cunknown>\n#2 0x561b2acc0ada \u003Cunknown>\n#3 0x561b2ad133d8 \u003Cunknown>\n#4 0x561b2ad0a168 \u003Cunknown>\n#5 0x561b2ad5b80c \u003Cunknown>\n#6 0x561b2ad4fe53 \u003Cunknown>\n#7 0x561b2ad17dd4 \u003Cunknown>\n#8 0x561b2ad191de \u003Cunknown>\n#9 0x561b2afe2531 \u003Cunknown>\n#10 0x561b2afe6455 \u003Cunknown>\n#11 0x561b2afcef55 \u003Cunknown>\n#12 0x561b2afe70ef \u003Cunknown>\n#13 0x561b2afb299f \u003Cunknown>\n#14 0x561b2b00b008 \u003Cunknown>\n#15 0x561b2b00b1d7 \u003Cunknown>\n#16 0x561b2b01d124 \u003Cunknown>\n#17 0x7f19cb085ac3 \u003Cunknown>\n"}} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '769', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
2024-01-06 02:53:18,676 -  DEBUG -  Finished Request
2024-01-06 02:53:18,676 -  DEBUG -  Cleaning up /tmp/.seleniumwire/storage-0b3741c8-e16b-4f5a-92fe-7d561883851a
2024-01-06 02:53:18,679 -  ERROR -  Driver instantiation error Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:46716
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
#0 0x561b2b01df83 <unknown>
#1 0x561b2acd6b2b <unknown>
#2 0x561b2acc0ada <unknown>
#3 0x561b2ad133d8 <unknown>
#4 0x561b2ad0a168 <unknown>
#5 0x561b2ad5b80c <unknown>
#6 0x561b2ad4fe53 <unknown>
#7 0x561b2ad17dd4 <unknown>
#8 0x561b2ad191de <unknown>
#9 0x561b2afe2531 <unknown>
#10 0x561b2afe6455 <unknown>
#11 0x561b2afcef55 <unknown>
#12 0x561b2afe70ef <unknown>
#13 0x561b2afb299f <unknown>
#14 0x561b2b00b008 <unknown>
#15 0x561b2b00b1d7 <unknown>
#16 0x561b2b01d124 <unknown>
#17 0x7f19cb085ac3 <unknown>
, None
```

So far, I have tried:

1. Using a virtual display like Xvfb (however, these installations are not detected either by the app).
2. Adding the '--no-sandbox' option to my Options() instance.
3. Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome, seleniumwire, undetected-chromedriver, and Selenium.

System information:

1. python version: 3.10.12
2. flask version: 3.0.0
3. selenium version: 4.16.0
4. seleniumwire version: 5.1.0
5. undetected_chromedriver version: 3.5.3
6. chrome version: 120.0.6099.199
7. operating system: Ubuntu 22.04
8. nginx version: 1.18.0
9. uwsgi version: 2.0.23